# Removing end of colnames with variable lengths and patterns

Tags: r

I currently have a dataframe with colnames that I'm trying to truncate the end after the 2nd period.

Example below:

```
GTEX.W5WGY.1726.SM.4LMI5 GTEX.WEY5.1226.SM.4LMIQ
23 20
0 32
```

Ideal output:

```
GTEX.W5WGY GTEX.WEY5
23 20
0 32
```

I'm trying to get it to this output instead and have tried sub but it isn't working.

```
colnames(x) <- sub("..*.SM..*", "", colnames(x))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can change the pattern to capture the characters that are not a `.` (`[^.]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by a `.` and the second of no dots, replace with the backreference of the captured group

```
colnames(x) <- sub("^([^.]+\\.[^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", colnames(x))
```